# My properties are not listed in COM DLL object from MFC

Tags: c#, mfc, com

OK, this is my MFC code:

```
void CTestDlg::OnBnClickedButtonTest()
{
    MSAToolsLibrary::IMSAToolsLibraryInterfacePtr p;
    HRESULT hr;
    hr = p.CreateInstance(__uuidof(MSAToolsLibrary::MSAToolsLibraryClass));
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        __int64 i;
        p->SetPathXML(m_strPublisherDatabaseXML.AllocSysString(), &i);
        p->ReadPublisherData(&i);

        CString strName = _T("Andrew Truckle");
        CComBSTR bstrName = strName.AllocSysString();

        VARIANT_BOOL bResult;
        MSAToolsLibrary::_PublisherPtr pPublisher = NULL;
        hr = p->GetPublisher(bstrName, &pPublisher, &bResult);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            if (bResult == VARIANT_TRUE)
            {
                AfxMessageBox(_T("Found"));
            }
            else
                AfxMessageBox(_T("Not found"));
        }
        else
        {
            AfxMessageBox(_T("Failed"));
        }
    }
}
```

This is the method as defined in the TLH:

```
  virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetPublisher (
    /*[in]*/ BSTR strPublisher,
    /*[out]*/ struct _Publisher * * thePublisher,
    /*[out]*/ VARIANT_BOOL * bResult ) = 0;
```

For starters, I was not sure if I had to use `_Publisher` or `_PublisherPtr`.

This is the method in the C# DLL:

```
   public void GetPublisher(string strPublisher, out Publisher thePublisher, out bool bResult)
    {
        bResult = false;
        thePublisher = null;

        if(_PublisherData.PublisherDictionary.ContainsKey(strPublisher))
        {
            bResult = true;
            thePublisher = _PublisherData.PublisherDictionary[strPublisher];
        }
    }
```

What I don't understand is that in MFC, I can't see the publisher properties, like Name etc:

[image: Publisher code]

I can see it in the *Object Browser*:

[image: Browser]

This is the `Publisher` class:

```
using MSAToolsLibrary.PublisherEntry.AssignmentInfo;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace MSAToolsLibrary.PublisherEntry
{
    public enum Appointed
    {
        NotAppointed,
        MinisterialServant,
        Elder
    }

    public enum Serving
    {
        UnbaptisedPublisher,
        Publisher,
        RegularPioneer
    }

    public enum Gender
    {
        Male,
        Female
    }


    public class Publisher
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get => _Name; set => _Name = value;
        }
        private string _Name;

        public string Notes
        {
            get => _Notes; set => _Notes = value;
        }
        private string _Notes;

        [XmlAttribute]
        public Gender Gender
        {
            get => _Gender; set => _Gender = value;
        }
        private Gender _Gender;

        [XmlAttribute("Appointed")]
        public Appointed AppointedAs
        {
            get => _AppointedAs; set => _AppointedAs = value;
        }
        private Appointed _AppointedAs;

        [XmlAttribute("Serving")]
        public Serving ServingAs
        {
            get => _ServingAs; set => _ServingAs = value;
        }
        private Serving _ServingAs;

        public Availability Availability
        {
            get => _Availability; set => _Availability = value;
        }
        private Availability _Availability = new Availability();

        public Assignments Assignments
        {
            get => _Assignments; set { _Assignments = value; }
        }
        private Assignments _Assignments = new Assignments();
   }
 }
```

And the interface for the library:

```
[Guid("xxx")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IMSAToolsLibraryInterface
{
    void SetPathXML(String strPathXML, out Int64 iResult);
    void ReadPublisherData(out Int64 iResult);
    void GetPublisher(string strPublisher, out Publisher thePublisher, out bool bResult);
}
```

What do I need to do?

### Update

I am still missing something. I have switched off the `Make assembly COM visible`. I have added GUID's where I needed for it to compile again.

I then changed my Publisher class like this:

```
using MSAToolsLibrary.PublisherEntry.AssignmentInfo;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace MSAToolsLibrary.PublisherEntry
{
    [Guid("xxx")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public enum Appointed
    {
        NotAppointed,
        MinisterialServant,
        Elder
    }

    [Guid("xxx")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public enum Serving
    {
        UnbaptisedPublisher,
        Publisher,
        RegularPioneer
    }

    [Guid("xxx")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public enum Gender
    {
        Male,
        Female
    }

    [Guid("xxx")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface IPublisher
    {

    }


    [Guid("xxx")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class Publisher : IPublisher
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get => _Name; set => _Name = value;
        }
        private string _Name;

        public string Notes
        {
            get => _Notes; set => _Notes = value;
        }
        private string _Notes;

        [XmlAttribute]
        public Gender Gender
        {
            get => _Gender; set => _Gender = value;
        }
        private Gender _Gender;

        [XmlAttribute("Appointed")]
        public Appointed AppointedAs
        {
            get => _AppointedAs; set => _AppointedAs = value;
        }
        private Appointed _AppointedAs;

        [XmlAttribute("Serving")]
        public Serving ServingAs
        {
            get => _ServingAs; set => _ServingAs = value;
        }
        private Serving _ServingAs;

        public Availability Availability
        {
            get => _Availability; set => _Availability = value;
        }
        private Availability _Availability = new Availability();

        public Assignments Assignments
        {
            get => _Assignments; set { _Assignments = value; }
        }
        private Assignments _Assignments = new Assignments();
   }
 }
```

It compiles. Then in MFC I changed it:

```
void CTestDlg::OnBnClickedButtonTest()
{
    MSAToolsLibrary::IMSAToolsLibraryInterfacePtr p;
    HRESULT hr;
    hr = p.CreateInstance(__uuidof(MSAToolsLibrary::MSAToolsLibraryClass));
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        __int64 i;
        p->SetPathXML(m_strPublisherDatabaseXML.AllocSysString(), &i);
        p->ReadPublisherData(&i);

        CString strName = _T("Andrew Truckle");
        CComBSTR bstrName = strName.AllocSysString();

        VARIANT_BOOL bResult;
        MSAToolsLibrary::IPublisherPtr pPublisher;
        // So I don't need to use pPublisher.CreateInstance
        hr = p->GetPublisher(bstrName, &pPublisher, &bResult);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            if (bResult == VARIANT_TRUE)
            {
                AfxMessageBox(_T("Found"));
            }
            else
                AfxMessageBox(_T("Not found"));
        }
        else
        {
            AfxMessageBox(_T("Failed"));
        }
    }
}
```

But I still can't see any members in Intelisense. What am I missing?

### Update 2

OK, it seems that an `interface` can't include the fields? So I tried adding a public method to the class for the Name (as an example):

```
[Guid("xxx")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IPublisher
{
    string GetName();
}


[Guid("xxx")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class Publisher : IPublisher
{
    public string GetName()
    {
        return Name;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get => _Name; set => _Name = value;
    }
    private string _Name;
```

}

That worked. I could call `GetName` from `MFC`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IMSAToolsLibraryInterface
```

You know how to do this correctly.  But you did not do this correct for your Publisher class.  You probably discovered this and used another hammer to work around the problem, you used Project > Properties > Application > Assembly Information > "Make assembly COM-Visible".

That is a sledge-hammer solution to make all public types visible.  Now the [ClassInterface] attribute starts to matter, it determines how a class is auto-translated to an interface.  Required because COM only ever uses interfaces.  But the Publisher class doesn't have that attribute explicitly.  So you discovered that you don't like the default, ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch.  Which makes the autogenerated interface look like this:

```
interface _Publisher : IDispatch {
};
```

Just the IDispatch interface members are "inherited", none of the class members.  Just what you see back in the IntelliSense box, Invoke etc are the IDispatch interface members.  Useful to a scripting language, not useful if you like IntelliSense.

So do this the right way.  Consider turning the checkbox off, it didn't help you.  You can take the shortcut and apply [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)] to the Publisher class.  Not so clean because it also exposes the members inherited from System.Object and the type library will have a dependency on mscorlib.tlb.  Or the most righteous way, the one you know, declare an IPublisher interface.  And ClassInterface.None is now the right choice on your Publisher class.

Btw, do consider favoring ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual on your interfaces so your COM server is also usable from a scripting language.

Comment: An empty interface??  Do think about the consequences of that for a bit.

Comment: Sure, problem was, it would not let me add my `field` objects into the interface. But I think I should it. Please see updated question. Think I got it right now? Seems so. But, is it better to return the _Name rather than the Name object? Or is it not that important?

Comment: It isn't just C# that doesn't allow fields in an interface, COM does not either.  You use properties instead.  Well, you know how they work.

Comment: Alright, but I don't understand. `public string Name` is a public property. Yet, I could not work out how to add that to the interface. I created what I consider in C++ terms a public `method` to access the public `property`. But your comment alludes to being able to use a public property. I guess I got confused in the fact that a **private variable** is a **field**. And a property is a public access to a private field. But can you please clarify how exactly my public properties should be implemented in the interface then? My way, or some other? Thanks.

Comment: No, that's a field.  Put `{ get; set; }` after it and presto-chango, it is now a property.  You know this, your C# code is already properties.  Odd hangup.